# Cursor Move over list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using this on Jfiddle which is very similar to my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/pAu8Q/447/
I would like it so that when you scroll at the last Lorem ipsum it doesn't move everything. Basically I just want it to move when I scroll over the other Lorem ipsum that are not shown. 
HTML

```
<div id="holder"><ul id="scroll">
<li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
</ul></div>
```

CSS

```
#holder {
    background: pink;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#scroll{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#scroll li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));

    $("#scroll").css({
        'marginLeft': x + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: it works, so what's the problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't work the way I want it to. I want it to only move when try look for the hidden Lorem. Now it moves anywhere over the text.

Comment: oh I see - that'll be difficult then